# How to make constraints to coefficients?

Tags: r, constraints

I'm using R to solve a problem, here are my codes:

```
q2.quap <- quap(
  alist(
    result ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
    mu <- a + b*n + c*n^2 ,
    a ~ dnorm(80.6,6.35),
    b ~ dnorm(0,10),
    c ~ dnorm(0,10),
    sigma ~ dexp(1)
  ),
  data = l_2)
precis(q2.quap, digits = 4)
```

If I want to make "b" to be positive and "c" to be negative, what function should I apply in here?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a little bit of insight, when you use `dnorm()` and a mean of 0 and Standard Deviation of 10, in theory your  potential values will be equally distributed around the mean of zero...meaning some will be positive and others negative. That is just how `dnorm()` works

Comment: This is a insightful comment actually...Thank you for replying...

Comment: Please consider indicating which package you are using (both in the title and the text) and what kind of model you are trying to run.  Also, consider including a reproducible example.  Finally, if you want your posteriors to be strictly positive, probably you want your priors to be strictly positive as well.